# Converting IList to generic TResult, which can be IEnumerable or object

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I am trying to get some experience working with generics by creating a serializer.

I have a method to Deserialize, which I'd like to make use of generics with. It should be capable of taking objects or `IEnumerable`, such as `List<Person>`, `Person[]`, etc. `Deserialize<TResult>` is working.. sort of.. but I've hit a bit of a block in figuring out how to actually return my result as `TResult`.

Here is what I have:

```
    public static TResult Deserialize<TResult>(StreamReader inputStream)
    {
        if (inputStream.EndOfStream) return default(TResult);

        if (typeof(TResult).IsEnumerable())
        {
            Type itemType = typeof(TResult).GetItemType();
            IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType));

            MethodInfo deserializeMethod = 
                typeof(SimpleFixedWidthSerializer)
                    .GetMethod("Deserialize", new[] { typeof(StreamReader) })
                    .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { itemType });

            object item = null;
            do
            {
                item = deserializeMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { inputStream });
                if (item != null)
                    list.Add(item);
            } while (item != null);

            list.Dump();
            return (TResult)list;
        }

        ...
    }
```

Looking at the `Dump()` of the result, I can see it was properly deserialized into a `System.Collection.Generic.List` of type `Person`, and each `Person` was individually deserailized properly.. but I can't seem to figure out how to get from `IList` to my `TResult`. Example call of the method:

```
string testInput = "...";
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testInput)))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(mStream))
    SimpleFixedWidthSerializer.Deserialize<Person[]>(sr).Dump();
```

Which results in

> `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[UserQuery+Person]' to type 'Person[]'`

Does anyone know how I can convert my `IList` properly to my `TResult`?

Comment: Since you are ok with `typeof(TResult).IsEnumerable()`, just add a `switch/case` with all types you may have as generic type.

Comment: Since you are returning a hard coded list, why use generic?

Comment: Would it help if you did a `.ToArray()` to the `IList` before casting it to a `TResult` and returning it? A `List<Person>` is a `Person[]` but I don't think an `IList` is a `Person[]`.

Comment: @panoskarajohn - I am not returning a hardcoded list, I am parsing a fixed width file into whichever type is specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final route I went is this, which seems to work fairly well:

```cs
        public static TResult Deserialize<TResult>(BufferedStreamReader inputStream) where TResult : class
        {
            if (inputStream.EndOfStream) return default;

            if (typeof(TResult).IsEnumerable()) //arrays, lists, etc are a special cases
            {
                Type itemType = typeof(TResult).GetItemType();

                MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(FixedWidthSerializer)
                    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "DeserializeEnumerable")
                    .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(TResult), itemType });

                return methodInfo.Invoke(null, new[] { inputStream }) as TResult;
            }
            ...
         }
        private static TResult DeserializeEnumerable<TResult, TType>(BufferedStreamReader inputStream) //ignore the IDE, this is being called through reflection
            where TResult : class
            where TType : class
        {
            var list = new List<TType>();

            TType item;
            while ((item = Deserialize<TType>(inputStream)) != null)
                list.Add(item);

            if (typeof(TResult).IsArray)
                return list.ToArray<TType>() as TResult;
            return list.AsEnumerable<TType>() as TResult;
        }
```

Comment: I'd leave the cast of `list` to an `IList`. You could get rid of `addMethod` then. You could use `Array.CreateInstance`, `list.CopyTo`, and some casts instead of `toArray` if you consider that simpler. I don't think there's any getting around the `IsArray` check, and even that isn't going to get every case. What happens if you Deserialize a `HashSet<Person>` or a `LinkedList<Person>`?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson - I do wish it was possible to create methods where the generic where clause acted as an overload, which would make handling this a lot easier.Won't the LinkedList and HashSet work though as they both implement IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0):

Change your method so that it:

- Declares `list` as an object of type `List<>` (i.e. you can use the `var` keyword). You need this because `IList` does not have a `ToArray()` method.
- Restricts the type `TResult` to class types (this is needed in order for the `ToArray()` call to work later.
- Convert your list to an array by calling `ToArray()` before returning later.
- Make the cast using the `as` keyword so that it gets resolved at run time rather than being caught by the compiler.

These changes would change your method into:

```
public static TResult Deserialize<TResult>(StreamReader inputStream) where TResult : class
{
    if (inputStream.EndOfStream) return default(TResult);

    if (typeof(TResult).IsEnumerable())
    {
        Type itemType = typeof(TResult).GetItemType();
        var list = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType));

        MethodInfo deserializeMethod = 
            typeof(SimpleFixedWidthSerializer)
                .GetMethod("Deserialize", new[] { typeof(StreamReader) })
                .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { itemType });

        object item = null;
        do
        {
            item = deserializeMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { inputStream });
            if (item != null)
                list.Add(item);
        } while (item != null);

        list.Dump();
        return list.ToArray() as TResult;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: changing `IList` to `var`, ie: `var list = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType));` results in `list` being type `object` which doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Deserialize<Person[]>`, `TResult` is an array type. Since the object `list` is a `List` and `List` are not array, this cast: `(TResult)list` fail. Instead, call `Deserialize<List<Person>>` or `Deserialize<IList<Person>>`.

The source of the problem is that when `TResult` is `IsEnumerable` you return a `List` in all cases. But all `Enumerable` are not `List` (ex: array).

Answer (score 0):

OK, here goes attempt number two. The idea is that you don't want to complicate your code for no reason, so I have simplified the creation of the `List`. Then you add all your objects to it and you do all the casting before you return at the end. This requires a second generic parameter, which I have called `TItemType`:

```
public static TResult Deserialize<TResult, TItemType>() where TResult : class
{
    if (inputStream.EndOfStream) return default(TResult);

    if (typeof(TResult).IsEnumerable())
    {
        var list = new List<object>();

        MethodInfo deserializeMethod = 
            typeof(SimpleFixedWidthSerializer)
                .GetMethod("Deserialize", new[] { typeof(StreamReader) })
                .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { itemType });

        object item = null;
        do
        {
            item = deserializeMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { inputStream });
            if (item != null)
                list.Add(item);
        } while (item != null);

        return typeof(TResult).IsArray
            ? list.Cast<TItemType>().ToArray() as TResult
            : list.Cast<TItemType>().ToList() as TResult;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This was helpful - I went a slightly different route and created a second method called `DeserializeEnumerable<TResult, TType>` similar to this, but just worked with `var list = new List<TType>()` and my loop starts with `TType item = null;`. The only place I have to do any kind of cast is at the end, which I'm doing as `return list.AsEnumerable() as TResult;`. I still have to do the IsArray check but it works and is much easier to understand! Especially as I don't need reflection in my loop and can just do `item = Deserialize<TType>(inputStream);`